# Determine number of bytes in a line of a binary file Matlab

Tags: matlab, fortran, binaryfiles

I am working on importing some data interpretation of binary files from Fortran to MATLAB and have come across a bit of an issue.

In the Fortran file I am working with the following check is performed

```
CHARACTER*72          PICTFILE
CHARACTER*8192        INLINE
INTEGER               NPX
INTEGER               NLN
INTEGER               BYTES
c  This is read from another file but I'll just hard code it for now
NPX = 1024
NLN = 1024
bytes=2
      open(unit=10, file=pictfile, access='direct', recl=2*npx, status='old')
        read(10,rec=nln, err=20) inline(1:2*npx)
        go to 21
20      bytes=1
21      continue
      close(unit=10)
```

where nln is the number of lines in the file being read, and npx is the number of integers contained in each line.  This check basically determines whether each of those integers is 1 byte or 2 bytes.  I understand the Fortran code well enough to figure that out, but now I need to figure out how to perform this check in MATLAB.  I have tried using the fgetl command on the file and then reading the length of the characters contained but the length never seems to be more than 4 or 5 characters, when even if each integer is 1 byte the length should be somewhere around 1000.

Does someone know a way that I can automatically perform this check in MATLAB?

Comment: can you show the declaration for `inline`?  In any case one gotcha to this approach is it will break in event your file starts with several "lines" of all zeros.. (Which may very well happen assuming its a bit image )

Comment: I added in the declarations above @george.  How would this cause an issue if the file starts with all zeros when nln is the last record in the file?  (also, I didn't write this program, I just get to interpret it)

Comment: Ahh, I didn't get that you were reading the last line.  All you are in fact doing is determining the file size by throwing an eof error in event its an 8bit file..  Surely matlab has a simple way to query file size

Comment: thanks @george!! I actually figured that out from answering your question.  If you would like to write an answer I can accept it for you so you can get the points.  If not I'll simply answer for anyone else who might have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what we figured out was that the check is simply to see if the file is the correct size.  In Matlab this can be done as

```
fullpath=which(file);  %extracting the full file path
s=dir(fullpath);  %extracting information about hte file

fid=fopen(file_name,'r');  %opening image file

if s.bytes/NLN==2*NPX  %if the file is NLN*NPX*2  bytes
    for n=1:NLN  %for each line

        dn(n,:) = (fread(fid, NPX, '*uint16','b'))';  %reading in lines into DN

    end
elseif s.bytes/NLN==NPX  %Else if the file is NLN*NPX bytes
    for n=1:NLN  %for each line

        dn(n,:) = (fread(fid, NPX, '*uint8','b'))';  %reading in lines into DN

    end
else %If the file is neither something went wrong
    error('Invalid file.  The file is not the correct size specified by the SUM file')
end
```

where `file` contains the filename, `nln` contains the number of lines, and `npx` contains the number of columns.  Hope this helps anyone who may have a similar answer, but be warned because this will only work if your file only contains data that has the same number of bytes for each entry, and if you know the total number of entries there should be!

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, binary files don't have line lengths; only text files have line lengths. MATLAB's `getl` will read until it finds the binary equivalent of newline characters. It then removes them and returns the result. The binary file, on the other hand, should read a block of length `2*npx` and return the result. It looks like you want to use `fread` to get a block of data like this:

inline = fread(fileID,2*npx)

Your fortran code is requesting to read record `nln`. If the code you have shared reads all the records starting at the first one and working up, then can just put the above code in a loop `for nln=1:maxValue`. However, if you really do want to yank out record `nln` you need to `fseek` to that position first:

```
fseek(fileID, nln*2*npx, -1);
inline = fread(fileID,2*npx)
```

so you get something like the following:

Either reading them all in a loop:

```
fileID = fopen(pictfile);
nln = 0;
while ~feof(fileID)
   nln = nln+1;
   inline = fread(fileID,2*npx);
end
fclose(fileID);
```

or picking out only the number `nln record:

```
fileID = fopen(pictfile);
nln = 7;
fseek(fileID, nln*2*npx, -1);
inline = fread(fileID,2*npx);   
fclose(fileID);
```

Comment: thanks for the response steve.  I actually know all of that, but what I need to figure out is how to perform the test that is in the fortran code above.  At this point I don't particularly care what is in line NLN.  The test is just trying to read that record with 2 bytes for each integer (so it is trying to read 2*NPX characters from the NLN record).  If this fails (aka reaches the end of the file since NLN is the final record in the file) then the number of bytes per integer is one and subsequently there are only NPX characters per record.  That is what I need to figure out how to do.

Comment: @andrew If you want to check if you actually read 2*npx data you could check the `length(inline)` or you could use `[A,count] = fread(...)` and see if `count` matches the number of bytes you requested? Also, `feof(fileID)` will tell you if you reached end of file. Is this on the right track?

Comment: yes @steve.  I actually found a way to do it using a try-catch statement in matlab.  I will be posting an answer in a few minutes for anyone else who may stumble upon a similar problem  Thanks for your help!